# Firebase Database - Retrieving deeply nested data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to retrieve deeply nested data using a POJO class. Below is my data structure:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "User1": {
            "Email": "dfs@sdf.com",
            "Last_login": "5:15pm",
            "Username": "Test",
            "Leagues": {
                "FootballLeague": true,
                "CricketLeague": true
            },
            "Season": {
                "2017": {
                    "Points": 5,
                    "Results": 2,
                    "Matchday": {
                        "Matchdaydata1": "data1",
                        "Matchdaydata2": "data2",
                        "Fixtures": {
                            "Fixturedata1": "data1",
                            "Fixturedata2": "data2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "2018": {
                    "Points": 7,
                    "Results": 2,
                    "Matchday": {
                        "Matchdaydata1": "data1",
                        "Matchdaydata2": "data2",
                        "Fixtures": {
                            "Fixturedata1": "data1",
                            "Fixturedata2": "data2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my POJO class:

```
    public class Users {

 private String Username;
 private String Email;
 private String Last_login;
 private Map < String, Boolean > Leagues;
 private Map < String, thisSeason > Season;

 public Users() {

 }

 //All getters and setters 

 public static class thisSeason {
  private int Points;
  private int Results;
  private Map < String, matchdayData > Matchday;

  public thisSeason() {}

  //getters and setters

  public static class matchdayData {

   private String Matchdaydata1;
   private String Matchdaydata2;
   private Map < String, fixtureData > Fixtures;

   public matchdayData() {

    }
    //getters and setters

   public static class fixtureData {
    private String Fixturedata1;
    private String Fixturedata2;

    public fixtureData() {}
    //Getters and setters

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Here is how I'm accessing the data in the listener:

```
        List<Users> usersList= new ArrayList<Users>();
DatabaseReference fbDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        fbDB.child("Users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Users C = ds.getValue(Users.class);
                    usersList.add(C);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

**The problem:**

What I have currently implemented is storing all data up to *Points/Results* under Season.  I can retrieve this without any problems

For Matchday, I am getting null - it is not even recognising that there is data below it in my structure. How can I resolve this?

The datasnapshot returns all the data correctly, seems like it my POJO class is not set up correctly to store this nested structure

Comment: Thanks for your question, it solved my problem

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your json has problems with misplaced/missing commas and braces.  I think it should look more like this:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "User1": {
            "Email": "dfs@sdf.com",
            "Last_login": "5:15pm",
            "Username": "Test",
            "Leagues": {
                "FootballLeague": true,
                "CricketLeague": true
            },
            "Season": {
                "2017": {
                    "Points": 5,
                    "Results": 2,
                    "Matchday": {
                        "Matchdaydata1": "data1",
                        "Matchdaydata2": "data2",
                        "Fixtures": {
                            "Fixturedata1": "data1",
                            "Fixturedata2": "data2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "2018": {
                    "Points": 7,
                    "Results": 2,
                    "Matchday": {
                        "Matchdaydata1": "data1",
                        "Matchdaydata2": "data2",
                        "Fixtures": {
                            "Fixturedata1": "data1",
                            "Fixturedata2": "data2"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wrote the JSON out manually there as I have more data than this, just wanted to minimise the data for the convenience of this question. The JSON is fine in reality :-)

Comment: I see.  The thing I spotted that seemed important wasn't missing braces, but the missing comma between Results and Matchday since that's where you described having a problem.  I'll look some more at the Java code, but I just wanted to point that out in case you actually have that missing comma.

Comment: I exported the JSON from Firebase then cut chunks out - clearly didn't do it very well! I've now updated the JSON in the OP however, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid deep nesting in firebase. Iterating through deeply nested data can be a pain sometimes. Also if you want to add more data to your current data you will keep going deeper. It is better to use a flat structure read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). I'll suggest that you save the season data in a separate node and add the userId as a field. By using a flat structure you can query a subset of the data. Even though you may have to make multiple calls, it is better to get a small set that to have a giant json that is difficult to iterate.

For this particular response you need to get the value of the `matchdays` you need to query very deep by adding `ValueEventListener` on the child you want to retrieve.

```
fbDB.child("Users").child("User1").child("Season"). child("2017").child("MatchDay")addListenerForSingleValueEvent....
```